# Change innodb_io_capacity on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Our service uses `db-n1-standard-32` instance. The IOPS limit is read 40,000, write 30,000.
But our service seems to be limited at about 5000.
See the [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/63417f593c919107f07e20696ead921b).

I think it occurs from MySQL's `innodb_io_capacity`.

```
mysql> show variables like '%capacity%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| innodb_io_capacity     | 5000  |
| innodb_io_capacity_max | 10000 |
+------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Can I change the value?

Answer (score 1):

As of the moment it's not yet exposed in the [list](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags). You should file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) if you would like to make this a user changeable flag. Cloud SQL is a managed service and most flags are not exposed to users for the integrity and availability of the service e.g. some flags if not used properly may cause downtime and some unintended behavior.

[image: MySQL Flags]

Answer (score 0):

I am working for the Google Cloud Platform. To investigate this issue further, I believe it would be better to inspect your project and the specific Cloud SQL MySQL instance.

I recommend you to open a private issue by providing your project number and the Cloud SQL instance ID. Please use the following component:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202

Once you have created it, please let me know and I will start working on it as soon as possible. Meanwhile please provide me with the following information:

1. You have noticed this limitation because of production load?
2. Are you performing any performance tests that lead you to discover this limitations?
3. Have you encourage any specific problems?

As I mentioned above, please provide me with the information and let me know once the private issue is created, so I could start working on it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The IOPS is not limited by the “innodb_io_capacity” value.

As Christopher said, it’s not possible to change that value and there’s a good reason for it, as not only does it not noticeably improve performance but it also causes other issues like the per-transaction latency becoming more variable which affects many workloads.

We have run extensive tests to determine the value of this and other MySQL flags. Raising this limit doesn't improve performance, indicating that there are other bottlenecks that are hit before reaching the levels of read and write limits of IOPS.

InnoDB is using a doublewrite buffer which has hard-coded limits that don’t scale to those levels. This is used to prevent data corruption after certain types of failure. We'd like to be able to disable this, which should be possible if writes are atomic for the 16KB block size MySQL uses by default, although we can't guarantee that we'll make this available as part of Cloud SQL. It is currently possible for customers to manage MySQL in a Compute Engine instance in order to take advantage of [this BETA feature](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/16kb-mysql-best-practices).